# Gerund after as though, please, help to clarify

Tags: adverbs, gerunds, clauses, adverbials, test

They looked at Mary in surprise as though... her story.

A) not believing

B) not having believed

C) not believed

D) believed

Answer (score 1):

gerunds end up with 'ing' and a gerund is used as a "thing" or an "idea,"
in your case :
A) is correct
=> They looked at Mary in surprise as though not believing her story.

hope you find it helpful :)